# Park and Ride in Southern Denmark

Tags: automobiles, road-trips, denmark, copenhagen

A friend and I are planning a road trip through Denmark, but since we want to avoid the toll of the Storebælt bridge and the problems of having the car in Copenhagen, we'd like to park our car somewhere near Odense oder Nyborg. Is there some kind of Park and Ride where we can leave our car and continue to Copenhagen by train?

Comment: Have you google the city name + park & ride? If so, how is the outcome not satisfactory?

Comment: @Erik for Nyborg it justs lists result of trains and busses to Copenhagen without parking lots and for Odense mostly general information about parking in Denmark and bike rides.

Answer (score 2):

There is a large and AFAIK free parking lot right next to the train Station in Nyborg. However, not all of the express trains stop in Nyborg. All regular trains do, and they are only 15 minutes slower.
There is also paid parking inside the train station in Odense. All trains stop in Odense.